# Set Cognito Verification Type to Link in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to figure out how I can set the verification type from `Code` (default) to `Link` in my CloudFormation template.

In the website I can set it here: [image: example]

If I take a look at the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html) there is nothing mentioned.
My CloudFormation looks like

```
SomeUserPoolResourceName:
  Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
  Properties:
    UserPoolName: SomeResource_User_Pool
    EmailVerificationType: Link  # I want something like this
    EmailVerificationSubject: 'Your verification link'
    EmailVerificationMessage: 'Please click the link below to verify your email address. {##Verify Email##}' # fails because {####} is required
    AliasAttributes:
      - email
    AutoVerifiedAttributes:
      - email
    Policies:
      PasswordPolicy:
        - .... 
    Schema:
      - ....
```

Is it possible to configure this via CloudFormation?

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not possible currently. As per the updated [CreateUserPool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUserPool.html) API, a new VerificationMessageTemplate parameter will allow us to do this but cloudformation has yet to support this. AWS Support told that there is an existing feature request for the same. You can look into custom cloudformation resources as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. Quite what I've expected.

Comment: Have you seen any update on this?  I can't find any documentation anywhere

Comment: To anybody looking for help, the same parameter has been added to CF now however i am struggling with the difference between `VerificationMessageTemplate.EmailMessageByLink` and `EmailVerificationSubject` what is the different between the two?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
SomeUserPoolResourceName:
  Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
  Properties:
    UserPoolName: SomeResource_User_Pool
    VerificationMessageTemplate:
       DefaultEmailOption: CONFIRM_WITH_LINK
    EmailVerificationSubject: 'Your verification link'
    EmailVerificationMessage: 'Please click the link below to verify your email address. {##Verify Email##}' # fails because {####} is required
    AliasAttributes:
      - email
    AutoVerifiedAttributes:
      - email
    Policies:
      PasswordPolicy:
        - .... 
    Schema:
```

Change this part:

```
EmailVerificationType: Link  # I want something like this
```

For:

```
VerificationMessageTemplate:
  DefaultEmailOption: CONFIRM_WITH_LINK
```

Comment: You may check the cloud formation doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-verificationmessagetemplate.html

Comment: `Properties:
    VerificationMessageTemplate:
       DefaultEmailOption: CONFIRM_WITH_LINK` works for me - even in Serverless Framework.

Comment: @DanielGolgher Does this really work? Either way, it's probably more consistent to use the EmailSubjectByLink and EmailMessageByLink attributes that should be put as siblings to the DefaultEmailOption attribute, as per your documentation link.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom message lambda trigger, you can easily put your link in there.

```
<a href="https://[your domain]/confirmUser?client_id=[your clientId]&user_name=" + event.request.userAttributes.sub + "&confirmation_code=" + event.request.codeParameter + ">Click here to verify your account</a>
```

Comment: I like that idea because I can use it for a different problem. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [Daniel Golgher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12149139/daniel-golgher)

The workaround proved to be a good solution.

My Code looks like :

```
UserPool:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
    Properties:
      UserPoolName:
        Fn::If:
          - IsDevelopment
          - !Sub "${ApplicationName}-${Environment}-${User}-${Module}-user-pool"
          - !Sub "${ApplicationName}-${Environment}-${Module}-user-pool"
      UsernameAttributes: [email]
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email
      VerificationMessageTemplate:
        DefaultEmailOption: CONFIRM_WITH_LINK
      EmailVerificationSubject: verify your email id for ${ApplicationName}
      EmailVerificationMessage: Please click the link below to verify your email address. {####}
```